# Android: How to bind ProgressBar visibility via DataBinding?

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding, android-progressbar, android-viewbinding

I've tried a lot, honestly, but without success.

I have a `HomeViewModel` and some data in constructor:

```kotlin
class HomeViewModel(
    val userName: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData(),
    val userAvatar: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData(),
    // ...
    val showProgressBarUserInfo: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData()
) : BaseViewModel() {
```

and function `saveUserInfo()` in HomeViewModel

```kotlin
private fun saveUserInfo(user: User) {
    showProgressBarUserInfo.value = true
    getSomeOtherData()
    showProgressBarUserInfo.value = false
}
```

where function `getSomeOtherData()` also loads username and avatar, which are also binded

```xml
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View" />
        <variable
            name="vm"
            type="/path/to/HomeViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ProgressBar
            // ...
            android:visibility="@{vm.showProgressBarUserInfo ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

Also I've tried to create a function `setVisibleOrGone()` (extension or not)

```kotlin
fun View.setVisibleOrGone(bool: Boolean) {
    if (bool) {
        this.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    } else {
        this.visibility = View.GONE
    }
}
```

with @BindingAdapter("showOrHide") annotation and use it like

```xml
showOrHide="@{vm.showProgressBarUserInfo}"
```

but all of the above does not work.

**P.S.** data for username and avatar bind successfully, but progress bar is not showing.

**P.S.S.** Toolbar title and ImageView:

```xml
app:title="@{vm.userName}"
loadAvatar="@{vm.userAvatar}"
```

where `loadAvatar` is extension function

Please, help me

Comment: share bindingAdapter() method

Comment: @ShaluTD this is an annotation from `androidx.databinding`

Comment: This annotation can be used with a method. I thought you used in method

Comment: @ShaluTD yes, with `setVisibleOrGone` above

Comment: Have you set `binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner` in your fragment?

Comment: @SaurabhThorat, yes, in my `BaseFragment`

Comment: Did you check by setting your progressbar visibility to visible, if it is showing..

Comment: If getSomeOtherData is asynchronous then also the progressbar will not show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, when the user enters the application, I load some data, and at this time the progress bar should be visible.
I also use a Koin, and the HomeViewModel is initialized through it, respectively, the default value of the variable showProgressBarUserInfo is "false".
Apparently, at the moment of entering the `saveUserInfo()` function, the call of the `getSomeOtherData()` function was performed so quickly that the switching between the states of the ProgressBar was invisible.

I solved my problem by adding

```
init {
    showProgressBarUserInfo.value = true
}
```

at the top of my `HomeViewModel` with

```xml
android:visibility="@{vm.showProgressBarUserInfo ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
```